# Add NewLine in Webform When Pass the string from Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I Use MVC and sometimes need to pass the ViewBag.Message from Controller to view, and I need new line, I check this: `ViewBag.Message = SomeStrring + "/r/n" + SomeAnotherString;` Also this One `ViewBag.Message = SomeStrring + "</ br>" + SomeAnotherString;` but none of them work, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your slashes are misplaced. It's `<br/>`, and you must output it into the view using `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ErrorMessage)` to make it not escape the HTML :)

Comment: this is my exact code as you said: `ViewBag.ErrorMessage = e.Message + "<br/>" + e.InnerException.Message` but not work and show <br/> rather new line

Comment: Ah... You must use ``@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ErrorMessage)`` in your view to get the HTML to work ;)